# SandCastle not documenting return type

Tags: .net, documentation, sandcastle

Well i have a assembly with a few classes in and a interface with a few methods

Now when i run SandCastle on this assembly it generates a documentation like it should but if i go to a method on the interface it does not document the return type the way it does with the parameters..

My guess is that some thing is wrong in a style file or some thing but i have no idea what 
file to edit so what am i missing?

Update:

Im using

- [Sandcastle Help File Builder Utilities, version 1.9.3.0](http://shfb.codeplex.com/)
- [Sandcastle-June 2010 Release (Version 2.6.1062.1)](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/releases/view/47665)
- [Sandcastle Styles June 2010 (2.6.10621.1) - Rev 1](http://sandcastlestyles.codeplex.com/releases/view/47767)

[image: Missing return type]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this question? If so, please share ;)

Comment: Well im sorry to say no i didn't..

Comment: FYI - I found [this response](http://goo.gl/oi4my) from Eric Woodruff (SHFB Author) where he states that Sandcastle doesn't support the feature that you and I were hoping for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SHFB supports this function out of the box now days.